# Databinding with Control Properties in Winforms: Bind Enabled to state of Combobox?

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, windows-forms-designer

I have barely any experience with WinForms, but I'm fairly sure that this is a simple task. I just need to enable and disable the Enabled property of a textbox based on the SelectedIndex of a ComboBox.

Can this be done in the designer using DataBindings, or am I required to write a handler of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

You can bind it, but you have to write a Value -> Boolean converter to do the logic. I would suggest since winforms doesn't support the ViewModel paradigm you just go with an event handler as you'd likely have to define your databind in code anyway.

```
public void MyComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;
   if (box != null) return;

   switch(box.Text)
   {
      case "Value1":
      case "Value2":
      case "Value3":
         myTextBox.Enabled = false;
         break;
      default:
         myTextBox.Enabled = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I already have a lot of code like this, but I'm trying to move it towards the designer so that the code is less cluttered. It's a valid point that conversion is required in this case. I also have a similar situation where Enabled is bound to a CheckBox.Checked, but I can't seem to enter the databinding through the designer--only by manually coding it into the designer file, after which point it shows up (greyed out) in the designer.

Comment: To further specify, when I'm in the "Formatting and Advanced Binding" window opened from the "(DataBindings)" section in a control's Properties window, the "Binding:" list is always empty, and I don't know how to add things to it.